# how can I convert the string to array?

Tags: python

I would like to convert the long-string to an array to access detail inside. In my case, the string is like below

```
'[{"timestamp": 1567814400033, "fair_value": 0.01641267}, {"timestamp": 1567814400141, "fair_value": 0.01641273}]'
```

Desired result would be single array where contain dicts inside like this

```
[{"timestamp": 1567814400033, "fair_value": 0.01641267}, {"timestamp": 1567814400141, "fair_value": 0.01641273}]
```

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be needing to **import literal_eval from ast** module of python, it is a standard package installed in python which stands for **Abstract Syntax Trees**, more info here : https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html

Your code will look something like this:

```
from ast import literal_eval
your_variable = literal_eval('[{"timestamp": 1567814400033, "fair_value": 0.01641267}, {"timestamp": 1567814400141, "fair_value": 0.01641273}]')
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import json

array = '[{"timestamp": 1567814400033, "fair_value": 0.01641267}, 
         {"timestamp": 1567814400141, "fair_value": 0.01641273}]'
data  = json.loads(array)
print (data)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have solve this case by myself by using ast.literal_eval() lib

Answer (score 0):

Use the python [json library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). You can use it to parse your strings to json and also stringfy your `dictionary` or `arrays`.

```
import json

# Convert string to python object
data = json.loads(<JSON_STRING>)

# Stringfy python dictionary or array
string_data = json.dumps(<PYTHON_OBJECT>)
```